# Rails 4 - Don't include self in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `@articles` variable that stores the most recent articles in desc order. I am going to use this variable on my article show page. What is the best way to make sure it doesn't include the article it is currently on?

Here is my code:

```
@articles = Article.order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(32)
```

I also have an `@article` variable defined so it can find and display the correct article, as we are on the show page. I am assuming I can use this in some way to make sure that `@articles` doesn't include `@article`.. not sure the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have `@article` defined, you can do like below

```
@articles = Article.where.not(id: @article.id).order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(32)
```